# Adding a pattern-analyzer to a new index

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to store company data in *elasticsearch*, so am creating a new index to store the company data. One of the fields `IndustryHierarchy` is a comma-separated list of industry codes, and I'd like that to be individually searchable.

I am creating the index like this:

```
client.CreateIndex(ci => ci.Index("companydata")
    .AddMapping<ElasticCompany>(m => m
        .MapFromAttributes()
        .Properties(props => props
            .String(s => s
                .Name(p => p.IndustryHierarchy)
                .IndexAnalyzer("pattern")
            )
        )
    )
);
```

What I don't know is how to pass the regex to `IndexAnalyzer` so that it knows to split on a `,` (or whatever my delimiter happens to be).

---

I have tried to create the index manually using a `PUT`, using this command (I've used a `word_delimiter` for now, as it seems a simpler test):

`PUT http://10.10.0.223:9200/companydata`

```
{
        "settings": {
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "csv_filter": {
                        "type": "word_delimiter"
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "csv_analyzer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "csv_filter"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            "company": {
                "properties": {
                    "industryHierarchy": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "csv_analyzer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But if I do a search, the results don't seem to indicate something has been split:

`GET http://10.10.0.223:9200/companydata/company/_search&q=name:testco&pretty=1`

```
{
    "took" : 2,
    "timed_out" : false,
    "_shards" : {
        "total" : 5,
        "successful" : 5,
        "failed" : 0
    },
    "hits" : {
        "total" : 1,
        "max_score" : 0.5,
        "hits" : [ {
            "_index" : "companyinfo",
            "_type" : "company",
            "_id" : "22572",
            "_score" : 0.5,
            "_source":{
                "id": 22572,
                "name": "testco",
                "domainName": "www.testco.com",
                "revenue": "$250,000",
                "industryHierarchy": "media.news,media,retail.book,retail.electronics,retail",
                "addressCountryCode": "United States",
                "region": "California"
            }
        } ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209168/how-to-add-settings-property-with-array-value-to-es-index-using-nest/33210464#33210464) will point you a way how to create custom analyzer with NEST.

Comment: It does, but not enough to make it work. I'm going to work from the non-NEST JSON commands, and then work out how to do that in NEST.

Comment: Actually, I wonder if this is a conceptual problem on my part. How can I verify if it's worked or not? I have inserted some data where the `IndustryHierarchy` is a list of words separated by commas, but a search doesn't seem to imply that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fielddata_fields` to check if something has been split the way you wanted it to be:

```
GET /companydata/company/_search
{
  "fielddata_fields": ["industryHierarchy"]
}
```

If will give you something like this:

```
        "fields": {
           "industryHierarchy": [
              "media",
              "media.news",
              "retail",
              "retail.book",
              "retail.electronics"
           ]
        }
```

which indicates your analyzer works as expected.
What you see in `_source` when querying is just the exact text you indexed, not how it was actually parsed and indexed internally.

Comment: Perfect :) Turns out it was working all along, and I was just looking at the wrong output!

Comment: :-) you're not the only one. I've seen this confusion before. `fielddata_fields` is the way I always use to check my analyzers and I always recommend using it.

Comment: Thanks. Another thing that got me is that you can't 'legally' send a body with a GET. ES supports using POST though, so just have to remember to adjust all the examples.